# MS Bot Framework recording audio in group conversation in Skype for Business

Tags: skype-for-business, botframework

i have few questions that are very related to each other.
The general task in to record audio in conference in Skype for Business, ideally having audios separated for each of participants.

So the question consists of:

1) Does ms bot framework support Skype for Business, if not out of the box, maybe there some workarounds? I've also found some 3rd party libs: https://www.mindlinksoft.com/blog/mindlink-api-bot-framework and https://github.com/tahazayed/BotConnectorSkypeForBusiness but its not yet clear if they can do audio recording.

2)Does Skype for business \ Ms Bot framework supports processing of audio in group calls? From docs it seems like it only support audio in 1:1 call and also seems like bots process messages when only bot mentioned as a target, it doesn process all conversation in group chat.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Skype for Business is not a supported channel for MS Bot Framework.

Comment: yeah i know that its not listed in support channels, but what about other questions, do you have any info? Thank you